# jQuery multiple selectors same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery Code:

```
$('#select-adults-room-1').change( function () {
  og.removeErrorsOcio();
});
$('#select-kids-room-1').change( function () {
  og.removeErrorsOcio();
});
```

What is the best way to do it? I know this looks weird, but not sure how to improve it if it's possible.
I'm looking for some like this:

```
$('#select-adults-room-1','#select-kids-room-1').change( function () {
  og.removeErrorsOcio();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `$('#select-adults-room-1,#select-kids-room-1')`

Comment: Please read [the documentation for multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: [`Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: $('#select-adults-room-1, #select-kids-room-1').change(og.removeErrorsOcio());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass separate strings, place the comma between the selectors in a single string, like this:

```
$('#select-adults-room-1, #select-kids-room-1').change(function() {
    og.removeErrorsOcio();
});
```

Also note that you can pass the reference of the function directly to the `change()` method, like this:

```
$('#select-adults-room-1, #select-kids-room-1').change(og.removeErrorsOcio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to give common class to each element as

```
$('.your-element').change( function () {
  og.removeErrorsOcio();
});
```